# How to fix css flexboxes in Safari and Chrome 43

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

(English is not my native language, sorry)

I'm using flexboxes on Bootstrap 3 to put the same height on my columns.
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work properly **on Safari and Chrome 43** the last column is **automatically** on a second row for those browsers...

**The others posted questions don't treat about this specification neither on Safari 9.1 (OSX) nor on Chrome 43 (OSX).** It works fine on latest Chrome version.

I tried to add all prefixes but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I fix that?

**Demo :** [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/X8rr5UAqUw)

**Screen on Safari 9.1 (OSX) [bugged]**

[image: safari flexbox bug 1]
[image: safari flexbox bug 2]

**Screenshot on Firefox [not bugged]**

[image: firefox flexbox no-bug]
[image: firefox flexbox no-bug 2]

Thank you <3

## EDIT (22/05/2016)

If i change the flex in CSS it "works" but it doesn't respect the Bootstrap grid system anymore on any browser...

```css
.row-flex-accueil, .row-flex-accueil > div[class*='col-'] {  
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;

        -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 23em; /* this */
            -webkit-flex: 1 1 23em; /* this */
                -ms-flex: 1 1 23em; /* this */
                    flex: 1 1 23em; /* this */

        -webkit-box-pack: center;

        -ms-flex-pack: center;

                justify-content: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;

        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
                flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

**Screenshot on Safari (or any browser) : 1920*1200**

[image: safari update]

**Screenshot on Safari (or any browser) : ~1200*1200**

[image: safari little bug]

It's due to the `23em` in flex (If I'm right it's like a min-width) but i don't know how to change this...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I cut all the unnecessary code to put it on Bootply. This is a problem with blocks and it can be something inside it.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate ! Tell me where you see "Safari" and "Chrome v43" in the post you linked. I already asked for flexboxes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301187/centering-columns-in-flexbox but now it's a problem for Safari and Chrome v43. Stop editing without taking the time to read and to understand the question.

Comment: Your question was read. But apparently it was misinterpreted. Like you said, your English is not entirely clear. No need to get angry. I'll re-open.

Comment: But it may be closed again for not adhering to the guidelines. You should post enough code to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you and sorry for that. I added screenshots to improve the comprehension. Unfortunately, i can't post less code... It's blocks and it might be something into it... I understand there's many css but i already delete all the unnecessary code.